# Storing multiple types of a templated class into a container

Tags: c++, templates, containers

If I have a class with a template:

```
template<typename T>
class foo{
    T m_a;

    foo(T a){
        m_a = a;
    };

    ~foo(){

    };
};
```

Is there a way to store multiple variation of it ?

For example a vector that can store a pointer to `foo< int >` and `foo< string >` at the same time ?

**Edit more info**

I want to hide the implementation of this :

```
EventListener<string> ev1;
EventListener<int, int> ev2;
EventListener<int, string, double> ev3;

ev1(&Events::nameChange, &nameChangeCallback);
ev2(&Events::healthChange, &healthChangeCallback);
ev3(&Events::newUser, &newUserCallback);

ev1.processEvents();
ev2.processEvents();
ev3.processEvents();
```

into this:

```
EventManager em;
em.listen(&Events::nameChange, &nameChangeCallback);
em.listen(&Events::healthChange, &healthChangeCallback);
em.listen(&Events::newUser, &newUserCallback);
em.processEvents();
```

EventManager needs to create and store EventListeners into a vector to be able to remember them and delete them in the destructor.

That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: You could store pointer to base class for your user defined types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want e.g. `std::vector<foo<T>*>`, then you need to use a non-templated base class. It will need to use dynamic dispatch, so all of the public interface should be declared `virtual`.

```
struct foo_base {
    virtual ~foo_base() {}
    virtual void something() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct foo : foo_base {
    // ...
    void something() { /* do something with T */ }
};
```

Then your container is `std::vector<foo_base*>`. Another, perhaps better, way, is to use `boost::variant`. This limits the number of types you can store, but at the same time doesn't require base class and virtual interface.

```
typedef boost::variant<foo<int>, foo<std::string>> foo_variants;
std::vector<foo_variants> v;
```

Third way is to use `boost::any`, but that will require `boost::any_cast` wherever you use them, and allow absolutely anything to be stored in the vector.

```
std::vector<boost::any> v;
```

Comment: If something() needs to use T as an argument, eg something(T a). Would this still work?

Comment: @Blizter: No, unless you pack it into e.g. `boost::any` and unpack it in the concrete subclasses. The interface must be identical in all classes for base class approach to work.

Comment: Why is it necessary to declare the whole public interface as virtual? Couldn't I have a non-virtual public member and use it from the child template class?

Answer (score 1):

Different instantiations of a class-template are different (from the compilers perspective completely unrelated) types, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738405/how-can-i-store-objects-of-differing-types-in-a-c-container) applies.

Comment: That brings another question, if the class-template have the same functions, and they are stored. Can I call those functions without knowing their class-type ?

Comment: Now you are talking about polymorphism. You can do that by making your class-template inherit from a class that defines the functions you want to call polymorphically. Then you'd have to store pointers in your container, and you're good to go. While I was typing this comment, @Cat Plus Plus has posted an answer explaining that.