# c++ last element of a structure field

Tags: c++, set, structure, field

I get a structure, and I don't know the size of it (every time it's different). I would like to set the last place in one of the fields of this structure to a certain value. In pseudocode, I mean something like this: 
**structureA.fieldB[end] = cert_value**;

I'd do it in matlab however I cannot somehow find the proper syntax in c++, can you help me?

Comment: Does this `structureA` contain the size of `fieldB`?

Comment: Post some code. You must be knowing something based on which something else can be decided, because C++ is a statically-typed language!

Comment: How is fieldB declared? What type is it?

Comment: snippet: structureA[0].fieldB = 1.1, structureA[1].fieldB = 1.2, structureA[3].fieldB =1.3 and so on, meanwhile also structureA[0].fieldC = 15 etc, so structureA is array of different fields. I want to get to the last one in structureA and specifically to *.fieldB (say, float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Matlab, a [structure](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/structures.html) data type holds key-value pairs where the "value" may be of different types. In C++, there are some key-value containers available (associative containers like set, map, multimap), but they usually store elements of a single type. What you need if I understood it right is something like

"one" : 1

"two" : [1,2,5]

"three" : "name"

Which means that your structure resembles a [Python dictionary](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Dictionaries).

In C++, the only way I have heard of using containers with truly different types is by using [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html), which is accepted as the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4738405/735756).

If you pack a container with elements of different types, then you can use the end() member function of a container to get the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You need sizeof, this gives you the size of the array in bytes. Since you want the the index of the last element, you have to divide this number by the number of bytes for one element. You end up with:

```
int index_end = sizeof(structureA.fieldB) / sizeof(structureA.fieldB[0]);
structureA.fieldB[index_end] = new_value;
```