# Generic object vector/array, where each stored object has a different class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, vector

Is there any way of making a generic object vector or array, that allows me to hold objects of different classes in single vector or array.

I basically would like to know if I can switch out which versions of a class are called.

I.e. class square is replaced with class circle but both have a fuction called findArea so the main function wouldn't break when calling that object vector/array.

Comment: What can't you store pointers (`std::unique_ptr`) to the base class, of those classes, if you want to use only the common functionality?

Comment: Define "different class". Completely unrelated, or just different **sub**classes of a common base? See, by being vague, you've already elicited two completely different answers, of which presumably only one is actually applicable to you. If the latter, then simply research basic polymorphism; we don't need to explain virtual functions.

Comment: if the former, then: Possible duplicate of [How can I store objects of differing types in a C++ container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738405/how-can-i-store-objects-of-differing-types-in-a-c-container)

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of indirection.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> array_of_shapes;
```

Where all your shapes are classes derived of Shape.

Then if Shape has a `virtual findArea()` then you can always call `array_of_shapes[i]->findArea();` (assuming the spot is actually filled).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is polymorphism. This is a basic feature of C++ and other object oriented language.

You could declare a base class called `Shape` and inherit your `Square` and `Round` classes from it. Then, simply hold pointers (or better yet smart pointers) to it inside your standard library container of choice.

```
struct Shape {
    virtual size_t getArea() = 0;
};

struct Round : public Shape {
    virtual size_t getArea() { /* return calc */ }
};

struct Square : public Shape {
    virtual size_t getArea() { /* return calc */ }
};

main () {
    auto round = std::static_pointer_cast<Shape>(std::make_shared<Round>());
    auto square = std::static_pointer_cast<Shape>(std::make_shared<Square>());

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> vec;
    vec.push_back(round);
    vec.push_back(square);

    for (auto & x : vec)
        cout << x->getArea() << endl;
}
```

---

**Regarding your comment:**

> I basically would like to know if I can switch out which versions of a class are called.

You could achieve that using one of the following methods:

- RTTI: Use `dynamic_cast<>` to check if the object you hold is of a certain type:

  ```
  if (dynamic_cast<Round>(x.get()) != NULL)
      // x is a Round
  else if (dynamic_cast<Square>(x.get()) != NULL)
      // x is a Square
  ```
- Add a member to your classes, initialize it according to the type, and simply check it:

  ```
  struct Shape {
      enum Type {
           Round,
           Square
      }

      Type _type;
      Type getType() { return _type; }

      Shape(Type type) : _type(type) {}
      [..]
  }

  struct Round : public Shape {
      Round() : Shape(Shape::Round) {}
      [..]
  };

  // Check it later on using:
  switch (x->getType()) {
  case Round:
      // use
      break;
  [..]
  }
  ```
- Use `typeid()`. As long as your base class is polymorphic, it will give you the correct type information:

  ```
  if (typeid(*x) == typeid(Round)) {
      // x is a Round
  } else if (typeid(*x) == typeid(Square)) {
      // x is a Square
  }
  ```

Comment: If you ask me, `if`/`switch` on RTTI or some custom type info value is never the answer. The first part of your answer, about virtual functions, was enough; the rest, to me, is most likely only to confuse users who don't yet understand polymorphism into writing bad code.

Comment: @underscore_d, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Virtual functions already achieve the need for different behaviour based on the concrete type of the derived class, while preserving a common interface in the base. Ignoring that perfectly useful functionality of the language, and instead implementing your own subclass-specific behaviour using conditionals is pointless, ugly, hard to maintain, and requires the base to know details of its subclasses, so it's a code stink. Besides, you didn't explain why the OP needs to consider those as options when virtual functions exist; perhaps the answer is because there is no reason to!