# Making python like dict in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap

I want to make a map<,> in c++ just like with the following feature

KEY: std::string
VALUE: any type

For example my map should be of type

```
{
    string: int,
    string: char,
    string: vector<string>,
    // ...... and so on
}
```

I have tried the template approach and they are one time initialized

```
template  <typename T>
map<string, T> myMap;
```

ps: i have also tried with`map<string, auto>`. This approach will give a compile time error

Comment: You'd need to use something like `std::map<std::string, std::any>` but in most cases, having a heterogeneous container like this is a code smell of a poor design.

Comment: You could use a [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) as value type.

Comment: C++ is not a dynamic language (at runtime, anyway). What you are trying to do is probably a bad idea, depending what exactly you want to achieve. Related (but old): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738405/how-can-i-store-objects-of-differing-types-in-a-c-container

Comment: note that c++ and python have massively different strategies to solve certain problems. What do you need such a map for? If in pyhton you'd use a dictionary then it is more than likely that in c++ you'd choose a very different solution

Comment: @user463035818 the problem is solved thnx for your comment

Comment: haha no idea what you are actually doing. Taking your question literally the answer is `map<string,any>`

Comment: explain what you need the dictionary for, and people will show you why you don't need such a dictionary in c++ . if you really have a very rare occasion in which doing this makes any sense you can always use a format for generically storing values like json, bson, xml, yaml etc..

Comment: You may want to consider a `std::vector` of your structure, then make *index tables*.  An index table consists of a key field and a pointer or index to the element in the `std::vector`.  This is how relational databases work.  An index table means you don't need to sort your data in the `std::vector`.  Use `std::map` for the index table.

Comment: Please don't add SOLVED to the title. Write an answer instead (you can answer your own question).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: If the problem is solved, tell us how you solved it and accept your answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit by using the `any` :)

Comment: Write an answer please!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i wrote

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a link :(