# Array with elements of different types

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there any way to have an array consisting of different types in C++?

For example:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string cars[5] = {"BMW", "Audi", "Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "McLaren"};
    return 0;
}
```

This is how we normally create an array in C++ with a type specified.

But can we create an array like this in C++?

```
["BMW", 14, "Audi", 25, "Ferrari", 3, "Lamborghini", 7, "McLaren", 0]
```

And if I can't, is there any library or framework I can use to do this?

Comment: I see an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need this? Do you perhaps want an array of structs, or of `std::pair`s? Or maybe a `std::map` instead of an array?

Comment: I come from python and js, so I'm not really familiar with structs, so I was wondering if you could do the same with an array that's all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store objects of differing types in a C++ container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738405/how-can-i-store-objects-of-differing-types-in-a-c-container)

Comment: You can do it with an array of structs. Those aren't two different choices. In all likelihood they should be combined to solve the problem you are having.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Why?

Comment: Tip: `std::tuple`. C++ is a **strongly typed language** and there are rules. In Python you can get away with things that C++ absolutely, steadfastly refuses to even consider.

Comment: Those aren't good duplicates because they discuss how to store completely arbitrary data. The data in this question is well-structured with alternating strings and integers, so `any` and `variant` and the like aren't a good idea.

Comment: An 'I'm going to program C++ like it is Python' attitude is going to get you nowhere very fast. You need to spend some time to learn C++ and realise that it has it's own strengths and weaknesses compared to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to have an array consisting of different types in
> C++?

Yes, you can use `std::any` (since C++17):

```
std::any arr[] { "BMW", 14, "Audi", 25, "Ferrari", 3, "Lamborghini", 7, "McLaren", 0 };    
// (use vector or std::array instead)
```

You can also use a sum type like `std::variant` (since C++17) or `std::tuple`

Comment: `std::any` is a bad idea. The OP should learn to work with C++'s strong typing system, not try to emulate Python.

Comment: I agree that it's a bad idea to emulate python (not necessarily for learning purposes), but I think it's also bad to pretend these options do not exist